# What is the appropriate test to compare median wages?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, median

I am trying to find a test to compare how median wages have changed for college graduates after graduating. I am comparing the median wages for individuals based on the programs they graduated from (engineering, health, social science, etc.) and I am comparing their wages to themselves. So, for instance, I want to see how the median wages compare for 2019Q1 and 2020Q1. I am doing this for numerous college programs and different quarters so I would prefer to have a test that is quick.

I have looked into the Mood's Median test but from what I have read it is not the most reliable test. Furthermore, I have looked into Mann-Whitney test, however, given that the distributions may be different it will use the mean.

Comment: Mood's median test is reliable.  It does exactly what it does.  ...  Mann-Whitney test is not usually a test of means or of medians. ...  It sounds like you are looking for a two-sample test.  Would you rather use a test that compares many quarters simultaneously ? ... An approach to compare medians is to use quantile regression. ... Or you could set up a permutation test for medians.

Comment: I wouldn't need to compare quarters simultaneously. I am comparing 2019Q1-2020Q1, 2019Q2-2020Q2, 2019Q3-2020Q3, and 2019Q4-2020Q4